# How to create view on mysql where select statement has variable

Tags: mysql

I need to create a view on mysql where the query has distinct category name with variable. variable is used to generate the id for each category.

Here is my sql, can anyone help me out as I could not create a view with this SQL syntax.

```
create view cat1_view as (SELECT distinct categorylev1, 
       @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS id
  FROM topic t, 
       (SELECT @rownum := 0) r
group by categorylev1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
/*
create temporary table t(can_id int,    status varchar(20));

insert into t values            
(001 ,   'section 1 question 1'),    
(001 ,   'section 1 question 2'),   
(001 ,   'section 1 question 3'),  
(001 ,   'section 1 question 4'),    
(001 ,   'section 2 question 1'),    
(001 ,   'section 2 question 2'),    
(001 ,   'section 2 question 3'),    
(001 ,   'section 2 question 4'),    
(001 ,   'section 3 question 1'),    
(001 ,   'section 3 question 2'),    
(001 ,   'section 3 question 3'),    
(002 ,   'section 1 question 1'),
(002 ,   'section 1 question 2'),
(002 ,   'section 1 question 3'),
(002 ,   'section 2 question 1'),
(002 ,   'section 2 question 2'),
(002 ,   'section 2 question 3'),
(002 ,   'section 3 question 1'),
(002 ,   'section 3 question 2'),
(002 ,   'section 3 question 3'),
(002 ,   'section 3 question 4');

*/

select   distinct s.canid from
(
select   t.can_id as tcanid, t.status as tstatus ,
            case when @previd <> substring(t.status,1,9) then
            @sno :=if(@previd <> substring(t.status,1,9),@sno + 1,1) 
            else @sno
            end  as canid
          ,@previd:=substring(t.status,1,9) prevcanid
from t,
(select @sno:= 0) as sn
,(select @Previd:= '') as p
order   by substring(t.status,1,9)
) s
```